# Why I can't seem to order by 2 columns at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm currently stuck with this problem here. I'm trying to order 2 columns in DESC order, but only one seems to work at a time. I need both Main_Actor_Payment & Supporting_Actor_Payment to be ordered in DESC, but it doesn't seem to work. Please could someone help me out with this.

```
SELECT main_actor.First_Name,
        main_actor.Last_Name,
        main_actor.Payment_amount AS MAIN_ACTOR_PAYMENT,
        supporting_actors.First_Name,
        supporting_actors.Last_Name,
        supporting_actors.Payment_amount AS SUPPORTING_ACTOR_PAYMENT
FROM main_actor
INNER JOIN supporting_actors USING(MOVIE_ID)
ORDER BY supporting_actors.Payment_amount DESC, main_actor.Payment_amount DESC;
```

[Current output of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKZ0p.png)

Comment: What do you mean? I don’t understand

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data. What do you want it the result to look like if there aren't equal number of main actors and supporting actors?

Comment: Have u seen the image of output i have attached? As u can see the Main_Actor_Payment is not sorted in DESC order. I want both Main & Supporting Actor payment to be sorted in DESC

Comment: You posted what you get. Now post what you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you need to merge both `supporting_actors` and `main_actors` tables for a specific `movie_id`, then sort them descending based on the `payment_ammount` (For both main and supporting actors). If this is what you meant, you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT main_actor.First_Name,
               main_actor.Last_Name,
               main_actor.Payment_amount AS `Payment_Ammount`,
               "main_actor" as `Actor_Type`,
               MOVIE_ID
        FROM 
        main_actor
        union all
        SELECT
               supporting_actors.First_Name,
               supporting_actors.Last_Name,
               supporting_actors.Payment_amount AS `Payment_Ammount`,
               "supporting_actor" as `Actor_Type`,
               MOVIE_ID
        FROM 
        supporting_actors) a
WHERE a.MOVIE_ID = "La La Land"
ORDER BY a.`Payment_Ammount` DESC;
```